# Post to Azure Cosmos Db from NiFi

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, apache-nifi

I created Azure CosmosDb database and container for my documents.
I use NiFi as a main data ingestion tool and want to feed my container with documents from NiFi flow files.
Can anybody please share a way to post flowfile content to Azure Cosmos Db from NiFi?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE(2019.05.26): 
In the end I used Python script and called it from NiFi to post messages. I passed a message as a parameter. The reason I chose python is because it has some examples on official Microsoft site with all the required connection settings and libraries, so it was easy to connect to Cosmos. 
I tried Mongo component, but couldn't connect to Azure (security config didn't work), didn't really go too far with it as Python script worked just fine.

Comment: I would start with [native java API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-java-get-started#Connect) and ExecuteGroovyScript.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi Jay Gong, I think it is too complicated, I will try Mongo component today, thanks for your suggestion though

Answer (score 3):

Azure CosmosDB exposes MongoDB API so you can use the following MongoDB processors which are available in NiFi to read/query/write to & from Azure CosmosDB using Apache NiFi.

- DeleteMongo
- GetMongo
- PutMongo
- PutMongoRecord
- RunMonogAggregation

**Useful Links**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support

Answer (score 0):

Valeria. According to the [components list](http://nifi.apache.org/docs.html) supported by Apache Nifi related to Azure, you could only get Azure Blob Storage, Queue Storage, Event Hub etc,not including Cosmos DB.

So,I suggest you using [PutAzureBlobStorage](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-azure-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.azure.storage.PutAzureBlobStorage/index.html) to feed azure blob container with documents from NiFi flow files. Then please create a [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) pipeline in [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/) to transfer data from [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) into [Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db).